# Elatsicsearch aggregation equvalence of MongoDB $unwind step

Tags: elasticsearch

This question is very simple, is there in Elasticserch aggregation an equivalent of $unwind operation from MongoDB aggregation framework ?

Comment: It is possible. But implement it would be different. Pay attention that, when aggregating in ElasticSearch we receive buckets structure which is different from MongoDB. Maybe if example of specific scenario will be provided I could give an answer

Comment: Scenario goes like follows: I have documents with arrays in them and i want  them unwinded, that means for each value in that array return the parent document with only that value instead of full array. it is useful in counting stuff. So my solution was to use scroll and then unwind and count in a programming language.

Comment: Best practice for unwind would be aggregation. But its impossible to scroll over aggregation results.

Answer (score 0):

Important thing to pay attention is that, in contrast to unwind, ElasticSearch-aggregation won't reconstruct those documents but divide the aggregated results to buckets. Rest of the parse work will be imposed on the client.

Example, this query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "array_aggregation": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "array_items",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "other_field_aggregation": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "some_other_field",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Will result:

```
{
  "took": 59,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 163,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "array_aggregation": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "itemA",
          "doc_count": 3858,
          "other_field_aggregation": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "fieldA",
                "doc_count": 3858
              },
              {
                "key": "fieldB",
                "doc_count": 4050
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "itemB",
          "doc_count": 3858,
          "other_field_aggregation": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "fieldA",
                "doc_count": 3858
              },
              .
              .
              .
            ]
          }
        },
        .
        .
        .
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It is not the best solution for you but can be a good place to start.